# Error in phpMyAdmin after updating to v4.8.0: The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

`phpMyAdmin` worked fine with v4.7.9. Now after updating to v4.8.0 today (replacing the old `phpmyadmin` folder against the new one) I'm getting this message in phpMyAdmin:

> The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able
>   to cache templates and will be slow because of this.

I added the folder `./tmp/` like like this: `/usr/share/tmp`

phpMyAdmin is on: `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`

This didn't change anything.

Who know this error? What can I do?

Comment: run composer install inside the newly placed phpmyadmin folder

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Solution was to create a folder called `tmp` like this: `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp`.

Also make sure that the user (or group) running the webserver (e.g. Apache) has write access to the newly created tmp folder. Consequently, change the ownership to that user or add write access for all users. The latter one might not be really advisable.

Comment: This seems not be not working on Amazon EC2 instance running AMI Linux with manually installed phpMyAdmin. I tried to give the whole `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` folder, subfolders and files `chown` and `setfacl` to `apache` group and even `chmod` 777 to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp` but still get error. The only way to make it work is to set `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';` in `config.inc.php` but i'm not sure if this is the best way to manage it

Comment: `i'm not sure if this is the best way to manage it`; I think it doesn't matter. It's okay to do it this way.

Comment: I can't find `config.inc.php`. I only see the 'sample' of it.

Comment: `config.inc.php`should be in phpMyAdmin folder. Maybe it's in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`?

Comment: `/var/www/pma# chown www-data tmp` and any `chmod 7__` did it

Comment: Figured out it was due to SELinux. Tested it by giving `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp` command, after `chmod 777 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp`. No more errors reported on phpMyAdmin page. So i made the change permanent with `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp(/.*)?"` and rebooted. Ensured that the context was assigned proper permissions by checking `tmp` directory's line with `ls -Z /usr/share/phpmyadmin | grep tmp`. Error seems definitely gone.

Comment: The default config is config.sample.inc.php, phpMyAdmin will work out of the box with this. Copy to config.inc.php to override it.

Comment: @Fabius your comment about SElinux could be added in the reply.
It work for me.
Thank you.

Comment: Additional to @Fabius comment (which work for me), I figured out, that this TempDir issue are also caused of symlink (in my case). I've created an symlink from phpmyadmin to current Version (phpMyAdmin4.xxx.xx). Thats let me easily switch the Version as long as I test the installation. If your vhost point to this symlink, phpmyadmin has trouble to found ./tmp. So do it like Fabius suggest, add the Variable to config.inc.php and all works as expected.
Thanks Fabius.

Comment: Centos8, after semanage changes, do not forget to apply them:
restorecon -Rv '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp'

Comment: @Fabius `i'm not sure if this is the best way to manage it`. Works for me, so keep cool, I understand that setting the tmp dir to /tmp works because the user who is logged in to pma is owner of /tmp .

Comment: Creating a __tmp__ directory in __/usr/share/phpmyadmin__ ; Changing ownership of the directory (__sudo chown www-data:www-data tmp__) and finally assigning permissions (__sudo chmod 777 tmp__) worked for me in __Ubuntu Server 20.04__.

Answer (score 55):

simple fix is to create tmp dir in your phpmyadmin dir and set permission to 777

```
mkdir tmp && chmod 777 tmp
```

then

update your config.inc.php file add that line

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = 'tmp';
```

Comment: I did this, but added `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';` to the config file.

Comment: As per the suggestion from @skolind, the line for me was `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';`.  Problem has now been fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: For permissions issues on the directories, `777` gives every user full access to the directory. All you really need to do is `chown -R user:user ~/phpMyAdmin` where `user` is the name of the webserver user serving PMA; i.e. `www-data`/`nginx`/`apache`. This will solve any ownership conflicts in the total installation including `tmp`, without giving permissions to everyone.

Answer (score 17):

I had this same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 when I replaced the phpMyAdmin version from the package repository (v4.6.6) with the latest version (4.8.0). I don't know if you are running on Ubuntu, but maybe my response will be helpful to you (or others) who encounter something similar.

I put the new version in the standard location, `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/`, but Ubuntu's package installation of PMA puts some configuration settings in other places (see `/etc/phpmyadmin/` and `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/`). I found this setting in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`:

```
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

and sure enough that directory had been created and had the proper permissions. Wanting to stay as close as possible to the package installation settings, I made this change in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php` and pointed directly to that folder:

```
//define('TEMP_DIR', './tmp/');
define('TEMP_DIR', '/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/');
```

This setting is picked up by `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php` (which you are not supposed to edit) to set `$cfg['TempDir']`.

Comment: Confirming it worked for me also on Ubuntu 18.04 - upgrading from 4.6.6 to 4.8.0

Comment: ahhhh. nice. Worked like a champ.

Comment: Also change `define('CONFIG_DIR', ROOT_PATH);` to `define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');` in the `vendor_config.php` file to get rid of the secret passphrase (blowfish_secret) error

Answer (score 16):

In my case I added

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/temp';
```

to the

> config.inc.php
>   File within the phpmyadmin folder

Hope it will help someone

Comment: Remember to add required permissions if required.

Comment: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp (not temp) unless you added the folder that way

Comment: folder was added just that way

Answer (score 12):

Create a temp directory owned by and restricted to the webserver user. Do **not** place it inside of the phpMyAdmin webroot. (In this example, the webserver runs as `apache`):

```
mkdir -p /var/tmp/phpMyAdmin
chown apache:apache /var/tmp/phpMyAdmin
chmod 700 /var/tmp/phpMyAdmin
```

Next, set `TempDir` inside of phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/var/tmp/phpMyAdmin';
```

Any answer suggesting that you create `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp` is advocating bad security practice. This is generally true for temp directories, and explicitly stated [in the official phpMyAdmin documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html):

> For security reasons, all directories should be outside the tree
>   published by webserver.

Answer (score 8):

For me phpmyadmin dir was found inside `/opt/lampp/`

1. open teminal inside `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/`
2. give `root` privileges to the terminal by typing `sudo su` command.
3. now in same terminal use (`mkdir -p /tmp/`) hit enter
4. now, `chmod 777 /tmp`
5. Inside `phpmyadmin` directory there is a file `config.inc.php`. Open it using same terminal .
6. add this line `$cfg['TempDir'] = /tmp;`  and Save.
7. Now you are good to go , just reload the tab and the error will be gone.

Comment: This is insecure, as you're giving other users the possibility to read the tmp files. This could lead to data being stolen.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `tmp` folder in the base directory of the phpMyAdmin install (e.g. `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp`), and make sure that it is writable by the user that PHP is running under.

Answer (score 4):

From the [phpMyAdmin documentation:](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)

```
$cfg['TempDir']
    Type:   string
    Default value:  './tmp/'
```

The name of the directory where temporary files can be stored.
It is used for several purposes, currently:

The templates cache which speeds up page loading.
        ESRI Shapefiles import, see 6.30 Import: How can I import ESRI Shapefiles?.

To work around limitations of open_basedir for uploaded files, see 1.11 I get an ‘open_basedir restriction’ while uploading a file from the import tab..

This directory should have as strict permissions as possible as the only user required to access this directory is the one who runs the webserver. If you have root privileges, simply make this user owner of this directory and make it accessible only by it:

```
chown www-data:www-data tmp
chmod 700 tmp
```

If you cannot change owner of the directory, you can achieve a similar setup using ACL:

```
chmod 700 tmp
setfacl -m "g:www-data:rwx" tmp
setfacl -d -m "g:www-data:rwx" tmp
```

If neither of above works for you, you can still make the directory chmod 777, but it might impose risk of other users on system reading and writing data in this directory.

Answer (score 3):

well,in my case this error has occured when i was using ubuntu 18.04.
All you need is to go to the installation directory (in ubuntu - opt/lampp/phpmyadmin)
and create a folder tmp with all the suitable read/write permissions.

Follow these steps in case of ubuntu-

1.go to the PMA installation directory by typing following commands in cmd-

> cd opt/lampp/phpmyadmin

2.Then type the following command-

> sudo mkdir tmp && chmod 777 tmp

and then you are done..!!
I hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

If the folder already exists for example from a previous installation:

```
chmod -R 777 PATH_TO_FOLDER
```

Therefore permission on subdirectories are also modified (recursively).

Answer (score 2):

1) create the tmp folder

```
mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

2) findout your php user

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

3) Change ownership of the tmp folder to the php user found in step 2

```
sudo chown -R step2phpuser:step2phpuser /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

4) Signout of phpmyadmin and sign back in

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message. I'm using Ubuntu16.04 with lampp. You should go to 'phpmyadmin' directory, in my case '/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/', create a new 'tmp' folder. Open a terminal window and:

```
cd YOUR_PATH_TO_PHPMYADMIN
sudo mkdir tmp
```

Now you have to change the group of the 'tmp' folder to give access to php user. In order to find it, you can create a php file inside your localhost directory, in my case 'htdocs'

```
sudo touch user.php
sudo nano user.php
```

Inside nano editor, type:

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

Then press CTRL + O and CTRL + X to save and exit.
Open the browser and type in your address bar

```
localhost/user.php
```

It shows your php user.

After that, go to the terminal and navigate to your recently created 'tmp' directory inside phpmyadmin directory and type:

```
sudo chgrp YOUR_PHP_USER tmp -R
```

And change the permission to the 'tmp' directory:

```
sudo chmod 775 tmp -R
```

I recommend never give 777 permission to any file.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

For Arch and Manjaro users:

Create a folder `tmp` at `/etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/` - `mkdir /etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/tmp`

Set permission to 777 - `chmod 777 /etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/tmp`

Add this line to the config file at `/etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` - `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';`

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but none of the answers above could solve.
In my case my php security settings was so strict protecting php to access directories out of scope defined in `open_basedir` located at my `/etc/php.d/99-security.ini`(which I added perviously from a security toturial and the settings also could be located at `/etc/php.ini` file in your case):

```ini
;; Limit PHP Access To File System
; Limits the PHP process from accessing files outside
; of specifically designated directories such as /var/www/html/
open_basedir="/home/:/etc/phpMyAdmin/:/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/"
```

change to:

```ini
open_basedir="/home/:/etc/phpMyAdmin/:/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/:'/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp/"  ;<== changing to this solved the prblem
```

you just need to add your own directory in error mesage ('/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp/') and the end of `open_basedir` option. Don't forget placing separator `:` before adding it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case [MacOs El Capitán/portuguese], the message was:

```
The $cfg['TempDir'] (./temp/) is not accessible
```

My solution, in xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = './temp/'; to $cfg['TempDir'] = '../temp/';
```

That is, I just added a point to the path... work's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed my `vendor_config.php` file to `define('TEMP_DIR', '/tmp/');` instead of `define('TEMP_DIR', './tmp/');`

This seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem, with the "temp" directory. The solution was to change the owner and group of the "twig" directory (inside "temp") to "apache" (both owner and group)

Comment: You were right. I [added it as feature request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14586)

Answer (score 1):

Create the `tmp` folder in the root of phpmyadmin files

In addition to that, you also need to provide all permissions to that folder. That's what I did in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer goes to centos 7 Sentora users,
**tmp** folder has to be created under phpMyadmin of Sentora as shown below

`cd /etc/sentora/panel/etc/apps/phpmyadmin/`
`sudo mkdir tmp`

> After creating the folder make sure you give Apache access permissions to the tmp folder

`chown -R apache /etc/sentora/panel/etc/apps/phpmyadmin/tmp/`

Answer (score 0):

simply go to the phpmyadmin folder and put this code

$cfg['TempDir'] = './tmp/';

and then check tmp folder is exists or not into phpmyadmin if not exists then create tmp folder and give read and right permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error message was as follows:

```
The $cfg['TempDir'] (/var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this
```

Then I navigate and checked the location. there was the tmp folder but was owned by www-data by default. After that, I make it writable by the user the PHP is running under. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

CD into the phpmyadmin directory, usually

```
cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Check if the tmp directory exists

```
ls -la
```

Make a directory if it doesn't exist

```
sudo mkdir tmp
```

Make sure your server owns the dir. Most probably it'll be owned by root. For apache, the user and group is www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data tmp
```

Check the permissions and ownership again by typing

```
ls -la
```

It should look like this:

[image: phpmyadmin cannot access tmp directory solutuion]

Apologies if this doesn't fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Manjaro KDE and this solution worked for me.

Open

> /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin in terminal

and write

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin
```

Then

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin
```

then create a folder called tmp;

In the same folder, open

> config.inc.php

and add this:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';
```