# How do I add line of code to config.inc.php in phpmyadmin directory?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm getting this error message in phpmyadmin:
"The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache   templates and will be slow because of this."

I followed the solution which was to go into the phpmyadmin directory and change the config.inc.php file to include this line of code `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';` Doing this resulted in an error message "Can't open file to write."

How do I correctly add the line of code to this config file?

Comment: The problem you are facing is related to filesystem permissions. Is it Windows, Linux or other? Please see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730100/error-in-phpmyadmin-after-updating-to-v4-8-0-the-cfgtempdir-tmp-is-no

Comment: I have this week the same problem. First I create the folder and give the permission. Then I put the full path to the folder "/path/to/phpmyadmin/tmp" as the value of the var

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu...you're right it had to do with permissions. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

According to the warnings in https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TempDir, it's not an ideal security practice to point this to the general `/tmp/` directory where other users and processes can access and manipulate the files. I prefer to make a tmp folder in the phpMyAdmin folder itself and stay with the default configuration directive for $cfg['TempDir']. An alternative would be to make a subfolder within /tmp (you may need to take precautions to make sure your distribution doesn't automatically purge the folder) and set permissions on that folder. At the very least, even if you're not worried about the security implications, you'll need to set the permissions such that the webserver process can write to that folder.

Or, just ignore the warning — phpMyAdmin will still work fine :)

Comment: When you say security implications, what does that mean? I am on a personal computer at home and I don't share it with anyone else. What kind of issues can arise from doing it this way?

Comment: In that case, probably nothing. In a situation with shared hosting or other users, they could potentially inject their own code in to your cached templates, causing you to run arbitrary SQL commands on their behalf under your authenticated account, including inserting, modifying, reading, and deleting data and MySQL users.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it seems obvious now but I'm new to this. I opened the file using sudo gedit from the phpmyadmin directory in the terminal and I was able to save the changes. Previously, I was trying to edit the file right in the window of my file manager. Thank you!